# Rails 4.1 bootstrap-sass cannot find fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I started a new rails project with bootstrap-sass in the Gemfile.

Ran the following:

```
bundle install
```

In my assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Started rails server

In browser, the link localhost:3000 shows

```
Showing /Users/XXX/work/YYY/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

couldn't find file 'bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
(in /Users/XXX/work/YYY/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

Extracted source (around line #5):
<html>
<head>
<title>YYY</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

Rails.root: /Users/XXX/work/YYY
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in
'_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1173424794489528152_70210002519360'
```

Using Rails 4.1.1 and bootstrap-sass 3.1.1
Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.1.1'
end
```

Comment: what does your application.css.scss look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the actual assets from the Github page for bootstrap-sass.

1. Download bootstrap-sass project, copy over everything in the folder "vendor/assets" to the same folder in the project

   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
2. Open config/application.rb, add the following line:

   ```
   config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
   ```
3. Renamed my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss to custom_bootstrap.css.scss

   ```
   mv application.css.scss custom_bootstrap.css.scss
   ```
4. Clear cache

   ```
   rake tmp:cache:clear
   ```
5. Restart rails server

Comment: Copy gem to your project, seriously? Then why use the gem in the first place?

Comment: I would welcome another suggestion, but I don't see any other answer here.